# AntlrGrammar.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [subquery]

Tags: parsing, recursion, antlr4, context-free-grammar, top-down

In Antlr4 direct left recursion is said to be supported. I can verify this with [expr]-rule in the grammar given below. Anyhow ANTLR4's grammar analysis throws the error for the [subquery]-rule, the second direct recursive rule in this grammar:

```
AntlrGrammar.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [subquery]
```

Again the subquery-rule is left recursive. There is no indirect recursion.

```
grammar GrammarSubspace;

DIGIT: [0-9];
INT:  DIGIT ( DIGIT )*;
LETTER : [a-zA-Z_] ;
ID :  LETTER (LETTER|[0-9]|'_');

expr: expr '*' expr // precedence 4
| expr '+' expr // precedence 3
| INT // primary (precedence 2)
| ID // primary (precedence 1)
;

rowsetoperator: ( UNION (ALL)? | INTERSECT | MINUS );

subquery:
( 
    TERMINALVARIANT  
  | (subquery rowsetoperator subquery)+
  |  '('  subquery  ')'
) 
;

    TERMINALVARIANT: T E R M I N A L V A R I A N T; // Placeholder for another UNTERMINAL that resolves into all terminals without indirect recurrence to subquery

fragment A: [aA];    fragment B: [bB];    fragment C: [cC];    fragment D: [dD];
fragment E: [eE];    fragment F: [fF];    fragment G: [gG];    fragment H: [hH];
fragment I: [iI];    fragment J: [jJ];    fragment K: [kK];    fragment L: [lL];
fragment M: [mM];    fragment N: [nN];    fragment O: [oO];    fragment P: [pP];
fragment Q: [qQ];    fragment R: [rR];    fragment S: [sS];    fragment T: [tT];
fragment U: [uU];    fragment V: [vV];    fragment W: [wW];    fragment X: [xX];
fragment Y: [yY];    fragment Z: [zZ];
```

Legal grammar inputlines for diffrent subquery-code would be:

```
TERMINALVARIANT 
(TERMINALVARIANT) 
TERMINALVARIANT INTERSECT TERMINALVARIANT 
TERMINALVARIANT UNION ALL TERMINALVARIANT 
TERMINALVARIANT UNION TERMINALVARIANT 
TERMINALVARIANT MINUS TERMINALVARIANT 
(TERMINALVARIANT INTERSECT TERMINALVARIANT) 
(((((TERMINALVARIANT INTERSECT TERMINALVARIANT)))))
```

etc.

The recursion has TERMINALVARIANT gives an exit-clause, thus the recursion is/can be finite.
Why do I get this error? How can I rewrite the grammar to avoid it?

Comment: Although it would be pretty weird but have you tried removing the brackets that surround all the subrules in `subquery`? Maybe this gets converted into it's own sub-rule during the build process, thus creating the mutual left-recursion...

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tested on this.  Actually it's the branch before, that causes the error. With the clause commented out, this compiles correctly.

subquery:
( 
    TERMINALVARIANT  
//  | (subquery rowsetoperator subquery)+
  |  '('  subquery  ')'
) 
;

Comment: Okay what about removing the `+` in that rule? Because thanks to the left-recursion it shouldn't be needed anyways...

Comment: That wouldn't be a solution. This would change the grammar. Actually this is a simplified stup out of a SQL syntax. There you are allowed to catendate an unlimited number of subqueries eg. with UNION ALL. Acutally I solved the problem but rewriting the syntax to reduce one level of left recursion in the offending line. It effectively seems so, that Antrl4 rewrites the line (subquery rowsetoperator subquery)+ into two seperates subrules and in the aftermat struggles about it's own indirect left recursion bann. Thus direct left recursion support  in Antrl4 still doesn't hold in every case.

Comment: Yes that is correct... But I'm pretty sure it wouldn't change the syntax if you'd remove the `+` though... Have you tried it? The only thing that _is_ gonna changed by that is the parse tree but you can still parse the same input correctly (the "new" parse tree is actually a better representation for the input in my opinion)